# Discover the object that an attribute belongs to?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a way in JavaScript to discover the object that an attribute belongs to? I know that sounds ridiculous, here's an example:

```
Obj = {};
Obj._name = "name";

var x = Obj._name;
```

In this example, is there a way to discover what object 'x' refers to?

Thank you

Comment: The assignment just copies the value, it's not any kind of reference to where the value came from.

Comment: what if five objects has the same string? or what if an object has another object as a property, how could you tell them apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no - there's no back-reference checking or anything like that available in JS.

The only way this would *kind of* work would be if you had access to all the objects in question, in some kind of a collection, and could check each one for the property value.

This just returns the first object with a value that matches though, it's not guaranteed to be the source of the value.

```js
var myObjs = [
  {name: 'one'},
  {name: 'two'},
  {name: 'three'}
];

function findObjWithVal(val, objs) {
  for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    for (var p in objs[i]) {
      if (objs[i].hasOwnProperty(p) && objs[i][p] === val) {
        return objs[i];
      } 
    }
  }
}

console.log(findObjWithVal('two', myObjs)); // [object Object] { name: "two" }
```

What you're asking for is only really possible in a tight-set grouping of objects, with unique property values, where you know `x` is always a property value of one of the objects from the set, and no other object will have that property value. Pretty specific use case.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work for me in this particular instance. That's okay though. Thank you for the answer! I'll just have to find another way to do what I gotta do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the object to be attached to the string variable, you could do something like this:

```js
var Obj = {
  _name: 'Chad',
  _address: '123 Main Street'
};

function string(val, obj) {
  var s= new String(val);
  s.obj= obj;
  return s;
}

var x = string(Obj._name, Obj);

document.body.innerHTML= x + ' ' + x.obj._address; //Chad 123 Main Street
```

Referring to `x` would return `Chad`.  But you have access to all the object's properties by referring to `x.obj`.